# Какого рода СМС?

Tags: грамматика, согласование

В словаре Лопатина СМС ж.р. и ср.р. Но будет ли корректно, если написать: "Пришл**а** СМС". Другое дело, сказать: "Пришла эсэмэска". Грамоту.ру не поймешь: то говорит: "Корректно: Пришло СМС", то: "СМС и ж.р. и ср.р".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Думаю, что непереводимой аббревиатуре "**СМС**" *нельзя* приписать женский род. СМС (= сообщение этого формального типа, СМС-сообщение) - среднего рода, поскольку согласуется по роду с видовым наименованием "сообщение", причём эту аббревиатуру нельзя трактовать как слово (одни согласные) и приписать ему грамматический род на основе сходства с существительным. Если же аббревиатуру мысленно перевести (служба коротких сообщений), с женским родом выйдет несуразица ("*служба пришла*"). Остаётся **средний** род (*пришло сообщение*).

"**Эсэмэска**" (неформ.; ж.р.) - слово, изначально образованое с окончанием, характерным для существительных **женского** рода.

Comment: а как быть с рекомендациями?

Comment: Применять из них только правильный вариант, он ведь тоже рекомендован :)

Comment: Да, но вопрос не в этом: ж.р. можно считать ошибкой?

Comment: В значении чего-то "принятого" я считаю ж. р. ошибкой. В других контекстах правомерность трактовки СМС как "службы мобильных сообщений" (я не слышал, чтобы это кто-либо произносил) является спорной: реально аббревиатура была транслитерирована с SMS (short message service).

Answer (score 5):

Из словаря: СМС [эсэмэс], нескл., ж. и с. (сокр.: служба мобильных сообщений).

1) Если СМС - это служба мобильных сообщений,  то ж.р.

2) Если СМС (СМС-сообщение)- это сообщение,посланное службой мобильных сообщений,  то ср.р.

3) Если эсэмэска (СМС-сообщение, разг.), то это ж.р.

Comment: А в чем разница между  1 и 2 значением? Одно и то же .

Comment: Служба, занимающаяся рассылкой сообщений,  и само сообщение - это совсем не одно и тоже.  Просто мы обычно пользуемся только аббревиатурой СМС, причем в упрощенном виде, то есть для краткости говорим СМС вместо СМС-сообщение. Так как это уже вошло в норму, то можно считать, что СМС - это и служба, и сообщение, то есть слово имеет уже два значения.

Comment: Все ясно. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Аббревиатура SMS может означать: SMS (англ. short message service — «услуга коротких сообщений»
Услуга женского рода.